# Which caching technique to be used for apache php

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Currently i m using shared hosting domain for my site .But we have currently near about 11,00,000 rows in one of the tables.So its taking a lot of time to load the webpage.So we want to implement the database caching techniques like APC or memcache for our site.But in shared domain we dont have those facilities available,we have only eaccelerator.But eaccelerator does not cache db calls,If i m not wrong.So considering all these points we want to move to VPS and in this case.which database caching technique we need to use APC or memcache to decrease the page load time...Please guide on VPS and better caching technique of two

Comment: 11,000,000 rows in a database table does not automatically equal a slow site or the need for a cache. What exactly is taking so long? You don't need all 11m rows on the same page, do you? If you're saying your database queries are getting slow, you can probably speed those up by using better queries and/or adding appropriate **indexes** on your tables.

Comment: we have to basically use like query over here.we are doing pagination also,displaying 20 records first and the count of 2 columns.we are using 2 queries only...How can we speed up the queries in this case sir without cache

Answer (score 0):

we have similar website and we use APC

APC will cache the opcode as well the html that is generated. This helps to avoid unrequired hits to the page

you should also enable caching on mysql to cache results of your query

Comment: We should also go for APC is it as like you guys are doing???And can it be implemented in Shared server

Comment: i dont think you can implement it in shared hosting environment since APC is loaded as a PHP extension.
you can implement that on VPS easily

Comment: So is there any major configuration of VPS that we need to see before going for APC caching like RAM,CPU or bandwidth??

Comment: nothing in particular....
i have a website working fine on 128 MB ram with APC set to use 64 MB and remaining for Apache / PHP / MySQL. So there is no set rule as such.

I suggest starting at 512 MB RAM and gradually going higher as and when needed

Answer (score 0):

I had a task where i needed to fetch rows from a database table that had more than 100.000 record. it was a scrollable page. So what i did was to fetch the first 50 records and cache the next 50 in the first call. and on scroll down events i wrote an ajax request to check if the data is available in cache; if not i fetched it from the database and also cached the next 50. It worked pretty well and solved the inconvenient load time.

if you have a similar scenario you might benefit from this approach.

ps: I used memcache.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I take it you're doing a `LIKE %..%` query and want to paginate the result. First of all, investigate whether FULLTEXT indices are an option for you, as they should perform better. If that's not an option, you can add a simple cache like so:

1. Treat each unique search term as an id, i.e. if in your URL you have `..?search=foobar`, then "foobar" is the id of the result set. Keep that in all your links, e.g. `..?search=foobar&page=2`.
2. If the result set does not yet exist (see below), create it:

   1. Query the database with your slow query.
   2. Get all the results into an array. Don't overdo it, you don't want to be storing hundreds of megabytes.
   3. Create a unique filename per query, e.g. `sha1($query)`, or maybe `sha1(strtolower($query))`.
   4. [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) the data and store it in the file.
3. Get the data from the file, `unserialize` it, display the portion of the array corresponding to the requested page.
4. Occasionally, delete old cached results. You can do that with something like `if (rand(0, 100) == 1) ..`, which will run the cleanup job every 100 queries on average. Strike a balance between server load and data freshness. Cache invalidation is a topic whole books can be written about, BTW.

That's a simple poor man's cache implementation. It's not great, but if you have absolutely nothing else to work with, it's better than running slow queries over and over.

Comment: The column on which i m doing the search in table,i have assigned that table as FULLTEXT but when i run the full text i.e. match query in place of like query i dont get any result.I m not able to get,why is it so..If u can please correct my fulltext query issue,i think my page load time will decrease.

Answer (score -1):

APC is Alternative PHP Cache and works only with PHP. Whereas Memcahced will work independently with any language.

Comment: So for my case,shud i go for APC in VPS???or is there any other caching technique which i can implmenet in shared hosting

Comment: In your case I will suggest to go for Memcached.

Comment: but we are looking for PHP only.Then why we should go for memcache.I fu can highlight point on this please

Comment: If you are looking only for PHP solutions APC is quite good. But Memcached also worked with PHP. If you need I can suggest few codes (Memcached) which I have done.

Comment: ya sure sir.it will be a great help if u share some link

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-memcached-interfaces-php.html. This is the best which I have used.

Comment: Memcached can only store 1MB data and I'm getting issue to store 19.4 MB data object in memcached